# Why the properties object out ouf my json file is undefined after callback function? React + D3

Tags: reactjs, json, properties, callback, undefined

im struggling with a second level callback function to console.log the name of the countries from a map of germany out of a json file.

In the first callback the console logs out the Response with all the data.

But in the second one, when i want to access the body with.json().then() the error
"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" comes.

```
           const promise1 = fetch("./ger_states_data.json");
           promise1.then( response2 => {
             console.log(response2);
           })



           const promise = fetch("./ger_states_data.json");
           promise.then( response => {
             response.json().then( content => {
              console.log(content);
           });
          });
```

when i try to access the properties via

```
console.log(dataset.properties)
```

it logs out undefined

This is the json file:

https://gist.github.com/DreckigerDaan/c245d6efb18b800f84887d477a7f7cf3

This is the console:

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAR5E.png)

I check my json file via https://jsonlint.com/ and it verify my file as correct
The file was a geojson file before, but found out that in react a json.file is better
The json file is correctly imported via

```
import dataset from './data/ger_states_data.json'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you host this JSON? It looks like the path of the request is wrong

Comment: do you mean the github gist?

Comment: No I mean locally, you have to serve the file so it's accessible form the browser

Comment: i dont really understand, im storing the json file in the src/data/ folder and if i just console.log out the dataset it logs out in the console, so he finds it, so it should definitly be accessible?

Comment: There is a difference between importing and fetching. If you want to fetch it, you have to store it in `/public`. (I'm assuming you are using `create-react-app`) https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: You can try running `fetch("./ger_states_data.json").then(r => r.text()).then(console.log)` and see what you are really fetching

Comment: ok wow, i was missing the json file in the public folder and it already solved the problem with the "unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" error, with your fetch function im fetching the .json file. how do i now can console log out the name of the country?